# Entity framework core entry state does not change in relational entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using entity framework core. I am adding a `Widget` using `Dasboard` object. And saving database. Following code was working before when `Widget` and `Dashboard` id type was `string`. I changed type of id to `Guid` (But I don't know if this is the cause of the problem). And now I am getting an  while saving changes error.

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0.  Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded
>   row(s)

```
    public async Task<Widget> AddWidget(WidgetCreateCommand command)
    {
        var dashboard = await _context.Dashboards.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == command.DashboardId);

        var widget = new Widget(command.DashboardId, command.WidgetContentId, command.GridsterSettings);

        dashboard.AddWidget(widget);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // error is in here.

        return widget;
    }
```

Entities are relational:

```
    public class Dashboard : Entity<Guid>
    {
        ....
        ....
        public ICollection<Widget> Widgets { get; private set; }

        public void AddWidget(Widget widget)
        {
            if (Widgets.All(u => u.Id != widget.Id))
                Widgets.Add(widget);
        }
    }

    public class Widget : Entity<Guid>
    {
        ...

        public Dashboard Dashboard { get; private set; }
    }
```

I have looked at breakpoint, and see the `_context.Entry(widget).State` is `Detached`. But it should be `Added`.
Why `_context.Entry(widget).State` does not set as `EntityState.Added` automatically?

If I set `_context.Entry(widget).State = EntityState.Added;` as manually, it works. But I was not doing this before.

Comment: May you show your mapping? And the building of DbContext?

Comment: I don't see how this could ever have worked without an Include of Widgets when fetching the Dashboard, unless you've already previously cached that particular Dashboard in another query in the same session. You should probably change it to: `_context.Dashboards.Include(d => d.Widgets).FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == command.DashboardId)`